# Animated/interactive graphs: SVG, Canvas or neither?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I am developing a visualization in form of graph with edges that may be curved and vary in color and thickness. The nodes on the graph contain an image and some text. The graph is animated and interactive (you can click and move the nodes) and uses force directed layout.

I want to support at least a large portion of smart phone browsers such as those on android and iphone devices as well as any modern browser on the desktop.

Is it possible to create such visualization without using either canvas or SVG?

If I must use one, which one would be a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible to do so with both technologies, but you should have in mind that they have different approaches.
I recommend you use canvas (there are lots of good libs out there such as [kinetic](http://www.kineticjs.com/)) because android 2.x doesn't support svg :(

Comment: I favor SVG for graphs (I like the Raphaeljs library), but I do agree that canvas would probably be better since you want to target Android phones.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely SVG if you want tooltips/hover effects. Because the elements in the SVG image are just XML tags you can add mouse event handlers to them in the same way you would elements in the DOM.